# git add/stage and commit single file in one go

Tags: git

Given a modified file i'd like be able to type something like:

**git qmit myFile.txt "my update description"**

qmit (quick commit) would stage and then commit immediately.

I know it is possible to do a bulk commit using:

```
git commit -a -m "i've committed all my files"
```

But i'd like to do it with a single file:

Here is my attempt creating an alias

```
[alias]
   qmit = !git add "$1" && git commit -m $2
```

but I get the following error when executing it

```
git qmit config.js "added configuration"
```

**error: pathspec 'configuration did not match any file(s) known to git**

So it's viewing the parameters as files.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `git commit`:

```
git commit -m "my update description" myFile.txt
```

Does exactly what you want.

Comment: The thing missing compared to the question is the path.